# Save As Using Variable Names Gives Error

Tags: vba, excel, save

Trying to save a new, not yet named, workbook (that I added using another sub) with variables for the name. When I place everything within the quotation marks it works to save (not with variables). But this code constantly gives the run-time errror '1004': Method'SaveAs'of object '_workbook' failed.

```
Sub SalvarTabela30()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim CompanyNameSave As String
Dim VencimentoSave As Date
Dim ContractNumberSave As String
Dim LastrowForSave As Long
LastrowForSave = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
CompanyNameSave = Range("A2")
VencimentoSave = Range("C" & LastrowForSave)
ContractNumberSave = Range("E2")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
   Filename:="\\dsapc429pfs.pactual.net\homefolder02$\wellsty\Desktop\" & _ 
      "Projeto - Marina\" & CompanyNameSave & " - " & ContractNumberSave & _
      " - Vencimento" & "(" & VencimentoSave & ")", FileFormat:=52

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible one of your variables contains a disallowed character?

Comment: Both my dates and my CompanyNameSave have either \ or / within them. Would that affect it? How can I create conditional formatting that would remove them from the CompanyNameSave. The date I can do. Something like If CompanyNameSave.Value Contains "\" Then...?

Comment: Yes, that would absolutely affect it.  Try `CompanyNameSave = Replace(Replace(CompanyNameSave, "\", "-"), "/", "-")` to take care of both back and forward slash.

Comment: @DavidZemens - Post that as an answer so New2VBA can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things that might cause an error with the `Save` operation but probably the most common is when we attempt to automate the filename creation, and don't account for illegal characters, which can't be part of a filename.

In your case, since you are using date values, the presence of either a `\` or `/` in the date format would cause an error.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) lists the reserved characters:

- `<` (less than)
- `>` (greater than)
- `:` (colon)
- `"` (double quote)
- `/` (forward slash)
- `\` (backslash)
- `|` (vertical bar or pipe)
- `?` (question mark)
- `*` (asterisk)

For your case, you may simply use a double replace:

```
CompanyNameSave = Replace(Replace(CompanyNameSave, "\", "-"), "/", "-")
```

However, that doesn't account for all illegal/reserved characters. It may be helpful to write a custom function that cleans filename strings:

```
Function CleanFileName(name As String, Optional replaceBy As String = "_")
Const reservedChars As String = "<>:""""/\|?*"
Dim i As Integer
Dim ch As String

For i = 1 To Len(reservedChars)
    ch = Mid(reservedChars, i, 1)

    name = Replace(name, ch, replaceBy)
Next

CleanFileName = name


End Function
```

You could then call this function, immediately before trying to save the file, like:

```
CompanyNameSave = CleanFileName(CompanyNameSave, "-")
```

**Note:** If you omit the optional `replaceBy` argument, it will default to using an underscore `_` to replace the reserved characters.

**Note also:** This does not take in to account whether the file already exists.